# Enabling hardware acceleration in electron app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder, hardware-acceleration

I am building an app using electron and react.
In that i need to conditionally enable and disable hardware acceleration of app. I can disable it as below. But I did not find any thing in electron documentation to enable it back. How can I do that?

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
....
....
app.disableHardwareAcceleration()
```

Comment: This method can only be called before app is ready.
once it started in this mode
you need to restart again.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it again passing false as an argument in this function:

app.disableHardwareAcceleration(false);

Answer (score -1):

[HW acceleration](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/offscreen-rendering) is enabled by default. If you want it to be like that it must be for all the application.

Edit 2022: By default is enabled but not activated. If the [GPUFeatureStatus object](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gpu-information-in-electronjs/) shows it is deactivated you should append some flags to the execution of your electron binary (or app package)